# Tailwind css не работает (python + node.js)

Tags: python, css, django, node.js, tailwind

Осваиваю Django. Среди прочего, есть момент с работой css. Подключил Tailwind, Django его подхватил. Задача в следующем: есть 4 элемента, они должны встать в контейнер и выстроится в одну строку (код ниже). Однако вместо того, что бы поставить элементы друг за другом в одну строку, страница не реагирует вообще никак. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что нужно поправить?

```
    <header class="container max-w-full flex-row items-center justify-between">
    <div class="flex-row items-center">
        <div>
            <a href="{% url 'rooms:home' %}">
                LOGO
            </a>
        </div>
        <div>
            {% block searchbar %}
                <form method="get" action="{% url 'rooms:search' %}">
                    <input value="" name="city" placeholder="Search by city">
                </form>
            {% endblock searchbar %}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        {% include 'partials/nav.html' %}
    </div>
</header>
```